# Tell Postman (standalone) not to urlencode the querystring

Tags: url, postman

I have a endpoint which expects the a query parameter to contain curly braces.

```
domain.com/path?filter={not}foo{and}{not}bar
```

The chrome app of Postman can handle this. But the Postman standalone version will produce a urlencoded version

```
domain.com/path?filter=%7Bnot%7Dfoo%7Band%7D%7Bnot%7Dbar
```

Is there a way to prevent Postman from doing that?

I saw that some things can be defined in `Pre-request Script`. But I didn't find the option to deactivate urlencoding.

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/158

Comment: @safinchacko so basically not possible?